# What is the difference between Publication list and Suppression list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist, suppressionlist

Hi i am confusing to analyse what is the **difference between publication list and Suppression list**.

Both are used to manage subscriber status,when we use **publication list** and when we use **Suppression list** in exact target.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They seems to me very much different to each other.

[Publication lists](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/publication_lists/)

1. Publication lists help you manage subscribers' unsubscribe or opt-out actions.
2. Having a separate publication list for each communication type (Newsletter, Weather Alerts, Coupons, etc.) enables you to honor an opt-out request from one publication type without unsubscribing that person from all previously subscribed-to publications.
3. Use a publication list to filter the audience of an email send, which ensures your publications are sent to the subscribers who want to see them.

[Suppression Lists](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/)

1. A suppression list is a list of subscribers that you don't want to receive your communications.
2. Suppression lists serve as a **do not contact list** for your email sends.
3. Examples of the types of addresses included on a suppression list are addresses with a history of spam complaints, unsubscribe lists from previous providers or advertisers, addresses of your competitors, and canceled customers.